# Error: min/max value in number fields

Tags: field, fieldtypes, error

Is there any reason why min/max value are limited to the following?

```
[9999999999999]
- Min is too big (maximum is 2147483647)
```

I need to add **ISBN** numbers which are 13-digits. Is there a reason for this min/max length, and can it be increased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers have certain limits in computer systems and storing (as well as working with) exceptionally large ones is cumbersome.

In the [database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html), the `int` (integer, a whole number) is limited to a range from -2147483648 to 2147483647. A `bigint` can range from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 but is less common. And I don't think Craft uses `bigint`s anywhere.

I know it's purely numerical, but could your ISBN numbers use a text field? Unless you're doing math on it then this should suffice. If you really want you could a new fieldtype that validates an ISBN number but saves as a `varchar` in the DB.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. My database knowledge is pretty poor so didn't realise this was a limitation of the db. I suppose a text field could do the trick, I can always check with Twig if it's numerical — I expect the alternative option you mention involves a plugin, and my php is nowhere near good enough!

Comment: @Rob I can recommend Marion Newlevant's [Match Input](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mn_matchinput) plugin. It provides a text field that gets validated against custom RexEx patterns, which you define in its field settings. To match exactly 13 digits use this expression: `/^\d{13}$/`.

Comment: @carlcs Ah, sounds good will check it out. Thanks.